# Client connects twice when using Postman to send requests?

Tags: java, postman, serversocket

I'm trying to create a server in Java using Sockets. I create a ServerSocket using `ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);` and then attempt to connect using `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`. I send the request through Postman.

My issue is that whenever I send a request, I get the output:

```
New client connected
input: null
closed!
New client connected
input: PUT / HTTP/1.1
closed!
```

I'm confused as to why the client connects twice, and why the first request is always empty.

Full code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((clientSocket.getInputStream())));

                String input = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("input: " + input);

                clientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("closed!");
}
```

Comment: Postman provides extensive debugging/logging output. What do you see in Postman? Do you see two connections?

Comment: This is normal with Postman and Socket connections - had the same issue when using Postman for a ServerSocket (I basically just made some dummy logic for it that if body is null, meaning postmans first connection return empty response). just use curl or something else if you don't want this behavior

Comment: *"I'm trying to create a server in Java using Sockets."* -  Please ... don't.  Use an existing server-side HTTP stack.  The world doesn't need yet another hand-built and probably non-compliant web service to deal with. If you are doing this to "learn how HTTP works", just read the specs / RFCs, or find and read the code of an existing (decent) implementation of the server side.

Comment: (If you are doing this as part of a course ... someone has their teaching priorities wrong ...)

Comment: @JimGarrison no, I only see one connection

Comment: @JAsgarov Thank you for this! Is it normal behavior for the requests from postman to sometimes fail randomly as well? It usually works fine, but sometimes I will have to restart my server for the requests to work

Comment: @StephenC of course, I would use already existing technology if I could. This is a class exercise

Comment: No, the latter is not normal. When I had to write a Java SocketServer for my university the whole class had the same issue of Postman making dummy/check connection with no parameters/empty body first - that is just something you have to expect. Doesn't happen with curl though. But the second postman request  behaves completely normally so I would debug that.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from the comments:

> This is normal with Postman and Socket connections - I had the same issue when using Postman for a ServerSocket (I basically just made some dummy logic for it that if body is null, meaning postmans first connection return empty response).
>
> Just use curl or something else if you don't want this behavior.

Using curl (or the python requests library) worked for me.